# Multiplying 2D Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I overloaded operator * which multiplying 2D arrays. I have some problems with multiplying, don't understand exactly an indexes when I am multiplying.

Here's some declarations:

```
int *const e;   //pointer to the memory storing all integer elements of A
const int row, column;  //r and c are the numbers of rows and columns respectively
```

And some code:

```
A A::operator*(const A& matrix)const    
    {
        MAT result(matrix.row, matrix.column);
        if (column == matrix.row)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.column; j++)
                {
                    result.e[j*row + i] = 0; 
                    for (int k = 0; k < column; k++)
                    {
                        result.e[j*row + i] += e[j*row + k] * matrix.e[k*row + column];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I know that I need 3 loops, I think I have some problems in

```
result.e[j*row + i] += e[j*row + k] * matrix.e[k*row + column];
```

Do you have any clue ? You can write me some ideas how can I figure out it myself, because I want to understand it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe change `column` into `i` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
result.e[j*row + i] += e[j*row + k] * matrix.e[k*row + column];
```

is broken. The product P of two matrices A (dim M,N) and B (dim N,P) has it's coefficient in position (i,j) defined by the following :

> P<sub>i,j</sub> = sum(k = 1..N, a<sub>i,k</sub> . b<sub>k,j</sub>).

Thus the line mentioned above should be :

```
result.e[j*row + i] += e[j*row + k] * matrix.e[k*row + i];
```

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks, but after modifications I have some problems with destructor if (e != 0) { delete[] this->e;}, error message: "Project name has triggered a break point" and program exits.

Comment: @Cieja A break point is a feature of a debugger ... You must have accidentally set one. As for potential destructor issues, since you didn't post neither your ctor or your dtor in your question, we cannot help.

Comment: I did not put any one, that's why I am asking. Ill check it again.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've written wrong. But I'm confused because I have no idea why it is a breakpoint triggered in destructor and I have to abort my program.

Comment: Everything it's working. It's was my fault. I've just initialized a result array with dimension 2x3 but should be 3x3.  Thanks for help.